# Ionic 3: Error setTimeout

Tags: ionic3

We are using:

- Ionic Framework: 3.6.0
- Ionic Native: ^2.2.6
- Ionic App Scripts: 2.1.4
- Angular Core: 4.3.5
- Angular Compiler CLI: 4.3.5
- Node: 6.11.2

(We also went to node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts and updated ws to 1.1.4 (As you do -_-))

when doing *ionic serve* we get this error:

Runtime Error

macroTask 'setTimeout': can not transition to 'running', expecting state 'scheduled', was 'notScheduled'.

We tried upgrading everything using *outdated* which is pretty much what all advice found on the subject boils down to. The error is still there sometimes. When you reload 1 out of 3 times there will be the error.

The oh so professional "fix" is as follows:

```
<script>
    window.uneffedTimeout = window.setTimeout;
</script>

<!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

<script>
    window.setTimeout = window.uneffedTimeout;
</script>
```

So my question:

Is there a way to achieve this that is applicable to people outside of mental institutions?

**Edit**

Since my initial salt fueled explanation wasn't as accurate as it should have been let me clarify:

The error does *not* happend because I call setTimeout in *my* code. Angular and/or ionics additions to angular call this under the hood when the page loads.
I cannot change the fact this call happens nor can I reasonably change how the call is made.

What seems to happen is that the polyfill generated just patches the browser provided setTimeout method with it own implementation. This implementation is either just faulty or does not work with the other part of the code.

This is evidenced by the fact that if we just revert setTimeout back to how it was before the polyfill messed with it, everything works fine.

Now what we want is the polyfill to either give us a functional implementation of setTimeout or just not mess with it at all. The "fix" accomplishes the later but in a very crappy way. I rather have a solution that doesn't require me to repair broken components during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(() => {
         someFunction();
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't see how this applies. I updated my question to better explain the actual error.
I don't call setTimeout myself. It happens in the framework somewhere. The problem boils down to the setTimeout method being patched in a faulty way by the polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of internal errors in your ionic project are usually due to incompatibility between the versions of your components. You probably have to upgrade or downgrade one of them. And make sure you are using stable versions whose release dates are not too distant in time. Start a new blank project with `ionic start` and write down the versions used in it's package.json.

For instance yesterday to have my project running at home I had to downgrade my ionic-cli to v3.9.2 with `npm install -g ionic-cli@3.9.2` and downgrade my node.js to v8.9.4. In Mac and Linux you can use NVM (node version manager) which allows you to switch quickly between different node versions. Remember to call `npm rebuild` or just delete your node_modules folder. Frequently I need to use `npm rebuild node-sass --force`.

Answer (score 0):

> For IONIC 3 use this

```
let timeInMs = 5000;
let timeout= setTimeout( () => {
     // your code
}, timeInMs );
```

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
 sleep(time: number) {
return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time)); }
```

Use like this:

```
 this.sleep(2500).then(() => {
  // your code here
});
```